# Using ReadOnlyCollection and a Getter

Tags: c#, deep-copy

Yesterday I asked a question about deep cloning a list and I got a wonderful answer, which you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847307/how-can-i-create-a-deep-copy-of-my-list-collection).

The issue I have is the answer uses `ImmutableList`and I've got no issue with it, it's just that if I wanted to use ReadOnlyCollection and **ensure** that I return a copy of my collection and that the one in the class cannot be modified.

I just wanted to know if the following is correct.

```
    private ReadOnlyCollection<Author> listofAuthors;   
    private List<Author> copyofAuthors;

    public Book(ICollection<Author> authors)
    {

        copyofAuthors = new List<Author>(authors);
        listofAuthors = new ReadOnlyCollection<Author>(new List<Author>(copyofAuthors));

    }

    public ICollection<Author> Authors
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<Author>(new List<Author>(copyofAuthors));
        }
    }
```

According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) `ReadOnlyCollection` is just a wrapper for a underly mutable collection. So if any changes are made to the underlying collection it would be reflected in the `ReadOnlyCollection`. The above code the getter returns a new List as a readonly collection.

Question 1:

Given the above code, any other code calling it will get a **copy of the private ReadOnly(new List())**, correct? Any changes that the user makes will not be reflected in the ReadOnlyCollection inside the Book class, right?

Question 2:

I understand `ImmutableList` is more ideal, but if I needed to use `ReadOnlyCollection<Authors>` is what I've done in the Constructor/Getter correct? or can it be implemented in another/better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
public Book(ICollection<Author> origAuthors)
{
    // We only need to allocate the ReadOnlyCollection once.
    this.Authors = new ReadOnlyCollection<Author>( new List<Author>( origAuthors ) );

}

public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; private set; }
```

In this code, `origAuthors` stores a set of references to `Author` objects. That collection is modifiable by whoever provided it. I'm also assuming that `Author` is a class and not a struct, and thus has reference semantics.

This code makes a copy of the list of references to `Author` objects, wraps that list with a `ReadOnlyCollection` instance, and exposes that `ReadOnlyInstance` instance through our `Book.Authors` property.

Since the `Book.Authors` property is ultimately referring to a copy of the list of authors, if we remove an element from `origAuthors`, then `Book.Authors` will not reflect it; it will retain the set of Authors it had previously.

For instance:

```
void Test() {
    List<Author> mutableAuthors = new List<Author>();
    mutableAuthors.AddRange( ... add 5 authors ... );

    Book testBook = new Book( mutableAuthors );
    mutableAuthors.Clear();

    // Prints 5.
    Console.Writeline( testBook.Authors.Count );

    // Throws an exception from ReadOnlyCollection.
    testBook.Authors.Clear();
}
```

However, so far, all we've talked about are a set of lists that refer to Author objects; we've not talked to the Author objects themselves. Are they mutable?

If so, no matter how one retrieves a reference to an Author, it may be possible for them to modify the Author object itself. Using a `ReadOnlyCollection<Author>` only prevents you from modifying which items are in the list; it does not prevent you from modifying the items themselves.

Consider the following code:

```
void Test() {
    List<Author> mutableAuthors = new List<Author>();
    mutableAuthors.AddRange( ... add 5 authors ... );

    Book testBook = new Book( mutableAuthors );
    mutableAuthors.Clear();

    // Prints 5.
    Console.Writeline( testBook.Authors.Count );

    Author someAuthor = testBook.Authors[0];
    someAuthor.ChangeName("A new name");

    // Prints "A new name".
    Console.WriteLine( testBook.Authors[0] );
}
```

If you want to prevent this, then make sure your design for the Author class is immutable - once it's constructed, don't provide any means for consumers to modify it.

Comment: Yes, Authors is immutable, I should have stated this.

Comment: Just one question, provided that Authors is immutable, which it is, I can use the ReadOnlyCollection as you specified without worrying that the user can change the internal(Book) collection, right? Which the first part of your code seems to specify.

Comment: @Svetlana - Bingo. Since you make a copy of the list, your copy won't change when the original list is changed. Then you need to worry about making sure nobody modifies your copy of the list; you do that by exposing it through the `ReadOnlyList<T>` wrapper class. Lastly, we need to make sure that the thing itself, not only the list of things, is immutable. But as you state, `Author` is immutable. So all of our bases are covered.

Comment: I would not recommend exposing concrete types (SOLID principles), instead change `ICollection` to `IReadOnlyCollection`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - "I would not recommend exposing concrete types". Where do you see one such type?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - "change ICollection to IReadOnlyCollection". Sure, if you have .Net 4.5. I strived to change the asker's code as little as possible.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Do you mean the ICollection in the getter or in the constructor?

Comment: @antiduh - Didn't you have IReadOnlyCollection in the getter, or am I not remembering correctly? if you did, please change it back, I like that approach better than ICollection.